# Get Parse Analytics Custom Dashboard

Tags: javascript, rest, parsing, parse-platform, analytics

Is it possible to fetch app analytics from Parse using a Javascript or REST API? I would like to show download numbers and custom events in my own dashboard.

Comment: Did you find a solution that works for this? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only push by REST API.
https://parse.com/docs/rest