# Accessing Parse analytics data using javascript SDK or Rest API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, analytics

I want to fetch parse analytics for my app using javascript or Rest API, is Parse giving support for that? I want to show these custom events in my own web based dashboard.
same question posted here:
[Get Parse Analytics Custom Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803036/get-parse-analytics-custom-dashboard)?

Comment: Did you get any answer to this? I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that **we can't** make query/retrieve but we can download Analytics Data in CSV format from the Analytics Dashboard.(Top-Right Button).

Some details - https://www.parse.com/questions/query-for-analytics-event-data